# Use of Group BY in more than 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made an table which has 3 columns

Table

[image: Designed Table]

In this above table there are 3 columns i.e Trandsaction, EmpID, Date having some data. I need to form a table using some queries so that in the result table I will get how many transactions done in each month by a particular EmpID.

So the result table must be like:

[image]

So how to get month wise number of transactions per EmpID?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text. (I.e. no images.)

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data, so you get at least one transaction count <> 1.

Comment: If, say, employee #14 didn't have a transaction in 2019-12, would you want to show `2019-12 | 14 | 0` in your result or no row for the employee in that month?

Comment: Please remove the tag `database`, because you have no question about designing a database. Add a tag for your DBMS instead (`e.g. mysql` or `oracle` or `sql-server`), so we know which you want a solution for.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes I will show 0 in Transaction column if Transaction was not happened for a particular month.

Comment: No. I don't think that you are using both Oracle and SQL Server with the same database. So, which *are* you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I m using Sql Sever.

Comment: If you want to return 0 for an employee when they have no transactions then you need to use a table of all the employees you want returned as a start for your query. To be honest this is nothing but a query with basic aggregation. The only difference is you want to group by the month and year of Date instead of just Date.

Comment: @SeanLange Can u please help me with the correct query for this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all employees (I assume you have an employee table).
2. Get all months (you could get them from the transaction table).
3. Cross join the two in order to get all combinations, because you want to show these in your result.
4. Outer join the transaction counts per month and employee (an aggregation subquery). SQL Server's date to string conversion is a bit awkward compared to other DBMS. You need to convert to a predefined format and use a substring of that.
5. Use `COALESCE` to turn null (for no count for the employee and month) to zero.

The query:

```
select m.month, e.empid, coalesce(t.cnt, 0) as transaction_count
from employees e
cross join (select distinct convert(varchar(7), t.date, 126) as month from transactions) m
left join
(
  select convert(varchar(7), t.date, 126) as month, empid, count(*) as total
  from transactions
  group by convert(varchar(7), t.date, 126), empid
) t on t.empid = e.empid and t.month = m.month
order by m.month, e.empid;
```

If you don't want all employees, but only those that have at least one transaction in some month, then replace `from employees e` with `from (select distinct empid from transactions) e`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Date, EmpID, COUNT(transaction)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Date, EmpID
```

To get the date like "YYYY-MM" use

for MySQL (replace the String with the date column):

```
DATE_FORMAT("2019-11-25 10:49:30.000", "%Y - %m")
```

for oracle:

```
to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: OP wants it grouped by YYYY-MM.

Comment: How to format in to  'yyyy-mm' and it includes Null values as count, so suggests some query which supports all?

Comment: @Code_is_Fun that is where the tag for the database is welcome :)